# How to convert String Date to hibernate Date

Tags: hibernate

is there any way to convert `String Date` to `Date` in hibernate

is my sql we use to_date function to convert String date to Sql Date.

**But can we do same with Hibernate ?**

**or is there any method to convert String date to hibernate date  ?**

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution

there is no function to convert `String date` to `hibernate date` in hibernate

1.we should have Date column in our db.
2.take String date and convert it into sql date and set the date value to date filed.

the above procedure solved my problem.